# uint_not_usable_without_attribute static assert failed when using numeric generator in karma rule

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit

I'm unable to use a numeric boost karma generator in a karma rule, as it seems because I somehow use a wrong iterator template parameter for the rule:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <boost/spirit/include/karma.hpp>

template <typename OutputIterator>
boost::spirit::karma::rule<OutputIterator, uint_fast16_t>
        int_rule{
    boost::spirit::karma::int_
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::string output;

    boost::spirit::karma::generate(std::back_inserter(output),
            int_rule<std::back_insert_iterator<std::string>>, 5);

    std::cout << "\"" << output << "\"\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Fails on clang and gcc with

> error: static_assert failed due to requirement
>   '!boost::is_same
>
> > , int_<15>, unused_type>, output_iterator >, int_<15>,
> >     unused_type> >::value' "int_not_usable_without_attribute"
> >                 BOOST_SPIRIT_ASSERT_FAIL(OutputIterator, int_not_usable_without_attribute, ());

When using the generator directly via `boost::spirit::karma::generate(std::back_inserter(output),
                boost::spirit::karma::int_, 5);` compiles and works, so what am I doing wrong? Which iterator instead of `std::back_insert_iterator<std::string>` do I have to use, in order to encapsulate a numeric boost karma generator into a karma generator rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot parentheses in the rule definition. It should be `uint_fast16_t()`, not a plain `uint_fast16_t` as described in the `Signature` section of [the rule documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/karma/reference/nonterminal/rule.html).

Comment: OMG I can't believe it, you right. The funny thing is, some karma rules I wrote before worked without the parentheses, e.g. one that is a type alias for a `std::pair<std::string,std::string>`

Comment: Actually I am surprised why Karma requires parentheses here, because Qi lifted this limitation for a long time already.

Comment: I hate the fact that this limitation was attempted to be lifted (I was aware that it didn't work always, not even in Qi). I think the library has enough "magic" as it is, and more ways to say the same are not better. Instead, I'd have loved better compile-time diagnostics for this kind of mistake.

Comment: I am also not a big fan of that change, but from [the commit message](https://github.com/boostorg/spirit/commit/e34a955f2fbbf374870dee3329f89805cd775e6c) it looks like JDG was very exited about it. What about fails, I can imagine only these: you are going to return Qi parser type, rule locals type, or rule encoding type - none of them you should do. And about compile-time diagnostics - it already said `int_not_usable_without_attribute` :-)